# Page is not getting submitted in Chrome due to Jquery function whereas it is working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to display spinning wheel while I click the button (MVC razor view) till the page load gets completed. I would like to achieve this through jQuery only, not through AJAX.

My table is having below entry -

```
<tr><td width="30%" align="center"><p><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload" /></p></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="middle" align="center">         
<div id="load" style="display:none;"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/loading.gif")" class="img-responsive" width="40" height="40" alt=""></div> 
</td></tr>
```

My jQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {       
        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
        $('#load').show();            
    });       
});

//$(window).load(function () {
//    setTimeout(function () { $('#load').hide() }, 5000);
//});

$(document).ready(function (){
     setTimeout(function () { $('#load').hide() }, 5000);
});
```

Now this feature is working as expected in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome. In chrome page is not getting submitted and displaying the loading image.
I know Window Load is not compatible with chrome and that's why I commented that and trying to achieve when document gets ready.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

move the setTimeout inside the click event, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {       
        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
        $('#load').show();
        setTimeout(function () { $('#load').hide() }, 5000);
    });       
});
```

This function will show the `#load` element and then wait 5 seconds after you click to hide it again.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {       
        $("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
        $('#load').show();
        setTimeout(function () { $('#load').hide() }, 5000);
    });       
});
```

```css
#load {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="load">Loading...</p>
<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I tried to do this but did not work in chrome. Fiefox is fine and working as expected.

Comment: This is working in chrome for me, try the snippet, it's probably something else causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

> I know Window Load is not compatible with chrome

It most certainly is :) and your code is correct which is somewhat confusing :). "document ready", get called before the window has loaded, which will explain the behaviour you are seeing.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { $('#load').hide() }, 5000);
});
```

This will hide a div the the id of "load" after 5 seconds. If this is not happening, there is other code on your page affecting it. Any errors?

Comment: No. I am not getting any error during page submission. I do not have idea about other code but noticed there is constant traffic of SignalR.

Comment: Few things to check. inside your function, try logging $('#load').length to make sure you have some matched elements. If you get 1 we are ok. If you get nothing, try sticking an alert in there. If you are not getting an alert the code is not being reached or something is preventing it from running

Comment: I tried to put with some unique name and also had console.log() after the show() method. It's displaying the value. I launched fiddler. Tried to send request from both Chrome & Firefox. Chrome request is not getting posted whereas firefox is at instant.
Another thing to note, if I comment above jQuery function then page is getting posted from Chrome. So some issue with this function only.

Comment: How are you posting? The above code has no form/action. The function above will have no affect on posting.